# Реализовать ограничение по времени, при нескольких неудачных попытках аутентификации пользователя к базе данных PostgreSQL?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, аутентификация

Каким образом можно реализовать ограничение по времени, при нескольких неудачных попытках аутентификации пользователя к базе данных PostgreSQL?
Допустим пользователь 5 раз ввел неправильный пароль, как сделать так, чтобы для следующей попытки ему пришлось подождать, к примеру, 3 минуты.
Реализация планируется с целью защиты БД от атак "грубой силой".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак штатными средствами самой СУБД.

На уровне расширения такую логику возможно реализовать через `ClientAuthentication_hook` функцию обратного вызова. Смотрите крошечный contrib `auth_delay` как пример самодостаточного кода расширения.

Возможно, реализуемо сторонними средствами вроде fail2ban того же.

---

Не имеет смысла защищать базу от брутфорса пароля. И я серьёзно. Если вам захотят навредить - открытого в мир порта базы уже достаточно самого по себе для проведения DoS атаки. Да, речь даже не про DDoS. Флудом на открытие соединения кладётся элементарно.

База не должна быть доступна по сети откуда не надо.

Comment: А если представить ситуацию, что сотрудник компании осуществляет доступ к БД интернет-магазина, которая находится на хостинге, то каким образом можно ограничить доступность БД через сеть?

Comment: делается VPN для сотрудников. Или ssh тунель как вариант.

Comment: А вот если ssh взять, зная все необходимые данные кроме пароля, может злоумышленник попробовать реализовать атаку перебором?